# How to set columns at the centre of the row in Android RecyclerView - GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, gridlayoutmanager

I am having `RecyclerView` with `Grid layout`. Everything works well.
But I need to set column at center horizontal. For example. I am having 18 items and span count is 4. For the last row, I have 2 item. these two items should be at the center horizontal instead of left.

This is my `RecyclerView`:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_option"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rv_answer" />
```

This is my `adapter layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marginVSmall"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/marginVSmall"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginVSmall"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marginVSmall"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <curvegraph.com.vijay.widgets.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_option"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="A"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textXLarge"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My Kotlin code to set `LayoutManager`

```
rv_option.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 4)
```

Here is my Kotlin Code :

```
 val grid =   GridLayoutManager(this, 8)
        grid.spanSizeLookup = object : GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {

            override fun getSpanSize(position: Int): Int {
                return if (position > 15) { // totalRowCount : How many item you want to show
                    2 // the item in position now takes up 4 spans
                } else 1
            }
        }
        rv_option.layoutManager=grid
        rv_option.setHasFixedSize(true)
        optionsAdapter.spanCountFun(8)
```

Comment: Would you please provide the java code you are tried.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this Hope this will help.

```
val gridLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 4)
    gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(object : GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {

        override fun getSpanSize(position: Int): Int {
            return if (position == 16) { // totalRowCount : How many item you want to show
                4 // the item in position now takes up 4 spans
            } else 1
        }
    })

    recyclerView.layoutManager = gridLayoutManager
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
```

Already have an answer of my own: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50247597/5167909

Comment: It works but only a single item moves. I am having 18 items span count is 8 In third row I need to set centre of the position it has only two items

Comment: Would you please provide the output screenshot that you want?

Answer (score 1):

it's impossible, because item of grid layout is fixed. 
U can using another trick, like using temp item for your list, but its can not help u if last row have one or three items

Comment: We have an option to set